# Invert rviz scan screen 180 degrees

Tags: gazebo, rviz, laser, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I reversed a 2d laser scanner that rotated 360 degrees through a servo motor. Because I turn it backwards, there is a reverse image on the Rviz platform. that is, the ceiling looks like a base, and the base looks like a ceiling.How to fix this problem on the RVİZ. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284427/invert-rviz-scan-screen-180-degrees/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please make sure you rotated the coordinate frame about the correct axes. ( z-axes). Seems like you have rotated it about y-axes. Follow the `right-hand rule` to decide which axes you need to rotate.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-03-06**:
Thank you Mr. @Brahmanage . but axis is true.I was spinning the lidar around the z axis. when I turn the lidar 180 degrees, that is, when I do -z I have encountered such a problem. I think I need to do something small in the URDF model, but I do not know.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-03-06**:
ı solved my problem Mr. Brahmanage. Thank you. I would like to communicate with you to apply your knowledge about a subject if possible.